How can a pyvista interactive graph be called using a tkinter button in such a way that the Tkinter GUI stays active?
Im trying to develop a small app which allows to plot 3d objects with pyvista while the GUI is provided by tkinter. While the pyvista graph is active, the GUI of tkinter becomes inactive which is what I would like to change.
Here a minimal example of what I mean (in this case I want to be able to write in the entry field while the plot of pyvista is active).
import tkinter as tk
import pyvista as pv
import threading


def create_pv():
    sp = pv.Sphere(3, (0,0,0))
    
    plotter = pv.Plotter()
    
    plotter.add_mesh(sp)
    plotter.show() 

def on_button_click():
    
    t = threading.Thread(target=create_pv)
    t.start()
    
    

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Simple Tkinter Window")

# Create a button and attach the function to it
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=create_pv)#command=on_button_click)
button.pack(pady=20)

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

# Run the application
root.mainloop()




Does somebody know how to implement the tkinter gui in such a way that that is possible?
Thanks for the help!
Tried calling the pyvista plotter both alone and with threading but both of them didnt work

Run it in a completely different process with multiprocessing module instead
